# How can you measure your battery drain rate?

Tags: battery, battery-life

Even turned off and with no background apps, my battery drains FAST. I would like to know how fast my drain rate is compared to other phones to find out if I should replace the battery.

What are some measurement methods?

Comment: @beeshyams edited

Answer (score 2):

- Comparing your device battery drain to another device battery drain is pointless. There are too many variables at play like Android Verizon, how well the OS is optimised, apps loaded, usage conditions and so on. See the section at end of answer for reasons of Abnormal Battery Drain
- Drain rate could be high, even when not used due to *Wakelocks*. See [wakelocks](/questions/tagged/wakelocks) and [greenify](/questions/tagged/greenify) tags that can help in reducing battery drain. [battery-life](/questions/tagged/battery-life) wiki has pointers as well
- See [How can I tell if I need to replace my battery?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/143797/131553) and in particular using the *Vbatt* app mentioned in my answer. This will not tell you whether you need to change your battery but helps you compare two batteries ( and is time consuming too)

---

See [this study](https://www.usenix.org/conference/nsdi13/technical-sessions/presentation/ma) for an interesting infographic 
[image]