# OnePlus 3 repair issue

Tags: battery, screen

The screen on my **OnePlus 3** phone was beginning to peel away from the bezel.  There was already a noticeable separation all the way along the top, and the problem was spreading downward along the sides.  Other than a touch-screen test I had to perform every time I activated the smartphone, it worked fine.  (It must have sensed something was weird with the screen, and made me touch four randomly placed circles before it would activate.)

I brought it to a local, independent smartphone repair shop about 12 days ago. They told me the battery was bloating, which is what was causing the screen to be pushed away from the bezel.  Since I don't have experience with this sort of thing, I just took their word for it, and let them order another battery.  Now I'm suspicious; battery life was fine.  I could use the phone (YouTube, games, phone) for 8 or more hours without needing a charge.  The phone would not be hot nor have a hot spot.

Ten days later (yesterday) they phoned me late afternoon, letting me know the battery had come in, and said I could bring it in today.  Their Saturday hours are 11 to 3, and the person on the phone was confident it could be completed same-day if I brought it in around 11.  I did.

The tech told me he could have it ready in a little over an hour.  I gave him 2 hours and went back.  The tech told me they must have gotten the wrong battery.  It fit, the connector was correct, and the phone came on, but it told him it had the wrong battery. He showed the original to me.  I could not see swelling, but the black paper backing was wrinkled as if perhaps it had maybe bloated and remained stretched out after the battery went back to normal size due to no load.  At least that is what the tech said.  He showed me three round holes on the back which he said had been caused by the failing battery.  He told me it would be a very bad idea to put the original battery back. He wanted to glue the screen in place over the new battery and see what the phone's status would be then.  So I'm doing that, and have another 40 minutes before I go back to check.  (I can't call; he has my only phone...)

**Am I getting the run-around from a clueless, perhaps dishonest shop?**

Unfortunately I prepaid for the battery and screen repair. If it is not working when I get back, I am not going to wait 10 days for another, possibly wrong, battery.  If they can't resolve the problem by the end of the day Monday, **what are my reasonable options?**

Comment: What is the update from repair guy? Curious

Comment: @beeshyams Just got back from shop. They had ordered another battery Saturday and expect it to get in b4 Thanksgiving. I remembered I still had my previous smartphone a Motorola/Google one.  Transferred SIM to it.  She explained that battery damage  (not round holes; I mispoke) resulted from them having to pry the old one out. I know your suggestion was to just accept the loss and go to authorized repair, but I don't totally distrust them and hate to waste the $128 already paid. If worse comes to worse, I'll buy a new one.  The OnePlus 6 is current and mine is a OnePlus 3.

Comment: Fine. All the best and hope you get it soon without issues

Comment: @beeshyams On Tuesday I picked up the phone, and it is working fine with the new battery,  including Dash Charging.  The screen was glued down and is longer trying to peal itself away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Your repair guy is either ignorant /or taking you for a ride or both**

Bad battery story by the repair guy is flimsy.

1. You had good battery life - 8 hours is actually pretty decent
2. Batteries are not balloons - if they are swollen, they stay swollen and don't regain original shape (on no load as you mention). See picture of  [badly swollen battery](https://www.123rf.com/photo_74440651_swollen-mobile-phone-battery-expired-or-low-quality-phone-battery-replacement.html)

Swollen battery *spin test* is one way of making sure it is bad. For details, see [this nice answer with embedded video](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/119162/131553)

3) Batteries don't make *round* holes if defective. They puncture, or explode at worst

You are being taken for a ride, sorry for that, but there is no polite way of saying that.

The only sensible option I see is take your phone to an authorized or reputed repair agency and forget this guy and the money lost